# Use Value outside of foreach in php

Tags: php, wordpress

Bellow code is my first code in my WordPress plugin:

```js
function link_in_bio_init() {

/* some codes */

  foreach ($obj['data'] as $post) {
    $pic_link=$post['link'];
    $i = substr_replace($pic_link ,"",-1);
    $i = substr($i, -11);
    register_setting(
      'page',
      'pic_link_' . $i
    );

    add_settings_field(
      'pic-link-' . $i,
      $pic_link,
      'links',
      'page',
      'section'
    );
  }
  
}
```

and this is my second code:

```js
function links() {
 $pic_link_id_text = 'pic_link_' . $i;
  $pic_link_id = esc_attr(get_option($pic_link_id_text, ''));
 ?>
 <div id="titlediv">
    <input id="title" type="text" name="<?php echo $pic_link_id_text ?>" value=<?php echo $pic_link_id; ?>">
  </div>
  <?php
};
```

But it seems that I can't use `$i` in other code. Any help with that?

There is 33 `settings_field` for wp plugin admin page that all of them has this HTML code format:

```html
<div id="titlediv">
        <input id="title" type="text" name="pic_link_00000000000" value="pic_link_00000000000">
    </div>
```

but I have 33 different results got from API and want to make this 33 fields different in `name="pic_link_00000000000"`.
This `00000000000` is `$i` value that should be different for each one.

/*** Edited ***/
This is how I use the API. I use token to get 33 last posts from Instagram.

```js
$access_token= 'MYTOKEN';
$photo_count= 33;
$json_link="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
$json_link.="access_token={$access_token}&count={$photo_count}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
```

the `$pic_link=$post['link'];` return me this kind of links : `https://www.instagram.com/p/00000000000`
Note: there are 33 different links.
so I use this code to create `$i` and get only `00000000000` part of the link:

```js
$i = substr_replace($pic_link ,"",-1);
$i = substr($i, -11);
```

So, now `$i%` is `00000000000`
Now I want to make an option for each link and store it in wp_options in my WordPress in different names with this format: `pic_link_00000000000`
Note: every `$i` is different, and there will be 33 options in the database with this format. My code for that is this:

```js
foreach ($obj['data'] as $post) {
     
    $pic_text=$post['caption']['text'];
    $pic_link=$post['link'];
 $i = substr_replace($pic_link ,"",-1);
 $i = substr($i, -11);
    $pic_src=str_replace("http://", "https://", $post['images']['standard_resolution']['url']);
     
 register_setting(
  'link-in-bio-page',
  'pic_link_' . $i
 );

 add_settings_field(
  'pic-link-' . $i,
  $pic_link,
  'links',
  'link-in-bio-page',
  'links-section'
 );

 }
```

In `register_setting` I'm creating an option with these names: `pic_link_00000000000` and in `add_settings_field` I'm creating a setting field in my WordPress admin page and call the `links` function every time on my loop for each one.
And this is my `links` function:

```js
function links() {
 $pic_link_id_text = 'pic_link_' . $i;
 echo $pic_link_id_text;
    $pic_link_id = esc_attr(get_option($pic_link_id_text, ''));
 ?>
 <div id="titlediv">
        <input id="title" type="text" name="<?php echo $pic_link_id_text ?>" value="<?php echo $pic_link_id; ?>">
    </div>
 <?php
};
```

but when I print `$pic_link_id_text` all I get is this: `pic_link_` without any `$i`.
when I use global, all the fields are the same and in the name of the last one.

Comment: Variables defined inside functions are available only inside those functions. See [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you want to pass a value from the first function to the second, `return` it.

Comment: @Alex Howansky I know and the wired part is that when I define $i outside the foreach, there is no difference.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. `$i` outside the function is a different `$i` than inside the function.

Comment: Where are you calling this function `links()`?

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov In `add_settings_field` array and the third value is the callback function.

Comment: I really cannot help you with that if you do not give me more information. Where do you get the `$i` from? How exactly do you call the function, can you pass variables to it? Show me your main code where you call both functions and also show me how do you get the `$i` from the api.

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov edited. It's all the way I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, you have to pass the variable to the other function. Example:

```
$var = functionOne();
$result = functionTwo($var);

function functionOne()
{
    return 2;
}

function functionTwo($var)
{
    echo $var; // This will output 2
}
```

The other way, although not recommended if you can avoid it, is to do it using globals:

```
function link_in_bio_init() {
  global $i;
/* some codes */

  foreach ($obj['data'] as $post) {
    $pic_link=$post['link'];
    $i = substr_replace($pic_link ,"",-1);
    $i = substr($i, -11);
    register_setting(
      'page',
      'pic_link_' . $i
    );

    add_settings_field(
      'pic-link-' . $i,
      $pic_link,
      'links',
      'page',
      'section'
    );
  }

}
```

and then:

```
function links() {
    global $i;
    $pic_link_id_text = 'pic_link_' . $i;
  $pic_link_id = esc_attr(get_option($pic_link_id_text, ''));
    ?>
    <div id="titlediv">
    <input id="title" type="text" name="<?php echo $pic_link_id_text ?>" value=<?php echo $pic_link_id; ?>">
  </div>
  <?php
};
```

**NOTE**: If possible, you should always avoid using globals.

Comment: cluttering the global space with variables is probably the last thing you should encourage... It might be helpfull to show _...pass a value from the first function to the second, return it_

Comment: Using globals is bad practice. If you want to get a variable into a function, pass it as a parameter. If you want to get a variable out of a function, return it.

Comment: I totally agree, but since we do NOT know if it is even possible to pass the variable to the 2nd function, I gave an alternate solution. As you can see, the first thing I said, was to pass the variable to the function. However, I will edit the answer to include a big note that warns not to use globals unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: with this solution, all the `$i`s are the same.

Comment: @ElyasBehroozizade and what exactly are you looking for if not this?

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov in each `settings_field` in wp, should be different `name="<?php echo $pic_link_id_text ?>` not all the same one.

Comment: @ElyasBehroozizade I am not sure what you want. I suggest editing the question with more information about what you currently have, what you want to have. Current output and Expected output should help too.